# Can you recognize the model of the car?

Tags: ford

I mean team, year, racing series, engine?
Is there some place in the internet where information about such cars can be found?

[image: unknown racecar]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's not about maintenance or repair

Comment: Maybe jump into [chat] and post this there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the side of the car, you can see the name *Freeman Racing Associates*. This refers to [Bill Freeman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Freeman_(racing_driver))'s team. Freeman is most notable for the team he created with acting legend Paul Newman. Freeman was also a driver himself. The team was called *Newman Freeman Racing*. Here is their team logo:

[image]

As far as the car ... I'm thinking it was probably a Ford, considering what was subtitled at the bottom of the picture, but I cannot find anything about what year this was (it was not 96, as it appears at the bottom under the "Turbo"). That would make it a Penske/Ford, as I believe only Penske was using Ford engines then. The only racing entry I can find for the team on the internet would be for the 1981 Indianapolis 500, where Michael Chandler drove the #68 (yes, this appears to be Freeman's Indy team number) to a 17th place finish. This car was a Chevy powered vehicle, though, not Ford. I found this information on [racing-reference.info](http://racing-reference.info/race/1981-06/UO). The car appears to be a late 60's/early 70's model Formula 1 car, considering the open and large wheels, lack of major hood scoop over the driver (they started putting really large ones on the cars in the early 70's), and small winglets. If you can believe the card, this was powered by a 3870cc V12 engine with a top speed of 310km/h ... at least that is what I believe it's trying to say. This car was probably run on the F1 circuit in Europe, but that is a total SWAG.